# Splitting a binary in file in C without corruption

Tags: c, file, io, binaryfiles

I have an assignment, where i have to take a word file (.doc), use filesystem IO code to read the file split the file in half and write each half to two separate files in binary mode. I wrote the below code and it successfully runs and produces the two files, even the size of the files are half of the original. however, when i go to open the word file they come out to be corrupted. this works fine with a .txt file, but my instructor said it should work for .doc and .zip files without file corruption. is there something wrong with my code? Thanks for any help I really appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *fileName = "1.doc";
    char *buffer = "a";
    int chunk;

    FILE *fd;
    fd = fopen (fileName, "rb");
    if (fd == NULL);
        ferror ("error");
    fseek (fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    chunk = ftell (fd) / 2;
    rewind (fd);                //open file, get size, set chunk = to half the file, rewind back to begining of file

    fread (buffer, chunk, 1, fd);
    fclose (fd);                //read the first half of the file into buffer

    fd = fopen ("1_1.doc", "wb");
    fwrite (buffer, chunk, 1, fd);
    fclose (fd);                //create new file, write the contents of buffer into it

    fd = fopen (fileName, "rb");
    fseek (fd, chunk, SEEK_SET);
    fread (buffer, chunk, 1, fd);
    fclose (fd);                //reopen original file, go to half the file, read the remaining half of the file and store in buffer

    fd = fopen ("1_2.doc", "wb");
    fwrite (buffer, chunk, 1, fd);
    fclose (fd);                //create a new file, write the second half of the file into it

    return 0;

}
```

i have tried both variations of

```
fwrite(buffer, chunk, 1, fd);
```

AND

```
fwrite(&buffer, chunk, 1, fd);
```

Comment: What happens if `fd=NULL`? (hint -- it doesn't exit). How much memory is allocated for `buffer`?

Comment: I don't see you allocate any memory for the buffer - therefore undefined behavior

Comment: `doc` and `zip` files have an internal structure. Simply splitting its in half will corrupt the file and make it unusable. Perhaps you misunderstood your instructor.

Comment: Are you supposed to sew the halves back together again too? Otherwise, what @Ari0nhh said.

Comment: `fwrite(buffer, chunk, 1, fd);` is right.

Comment: I agree with Ari0nhh. These kind of files have structure to them. You have to parse the structure in order to extract the content. Then you can divide up the content and create new files with valid structure to them. You don't have to worry about that with plain text files, they are just raw character data with no structure to them.

Comment: If you use this program to split a text file that uses a variable-byte encoding, such as utf-8, you may end up with 2 corrupted files.

Comment: thanks all, ill have to email my professor for clarification, thanks for the help.

Comment: If you are stitching the files back together before reading it, where you split doesn't matter.  It can be in the middle of a multi byte character without issue. But you need to write out **all** of the data.  A 115 byte file, you are splitting into two 57 byte chunks; but 57+57 only results in a 114 byte file.  You're missing a byte.  For text files, that might be a final new line, and go unnoticed.  For a file with structure, a .doc or .zip, that missing byte is file corruption!

Comment: @user3566683 You may also wish to email your professor that `fseek()` to the end of a binary file is undefined behavior per the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).  Per Footnote 234, p 267:  *Setting  the  file  position  indicator  to  end-of-file,  as  with `fseek(file,  0,  SEEK_END)` has undefined behavior for a binary stream ...* and **7.19.9.2  The `fseek` function**: *A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a `whence` value of `SEEK_END`.*  So, `fseek(file,0,SEEK_END)'` is a *non-portable* way to find the size of a file.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of issues, the primary of which is you are using buffer without allocating memory and are attempting to write to the address of the declared *string literal* `"a"` in read-only memory.

To correct this problem, you must:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
    char *buffer = NULL;
...
    chunk = ftell (fd) / 2;

    if ((buffer = malloc (chunk * sizeof *buffer)) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

Your use of `ferror` is incorrect, it takes a `FILE *` argument, not a `char *`:

```
    fd = fopen (fileName, "rb");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        ferror (fd);
        return 1;
    }
```

Finally, do not forget to free the memory you allocate when it is no longer needed:

```
    free (buffer); /* free allocated memory */
```

Putting it all together, you can do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    char *fileName = "1.doc";
    char *buffer = NULL;
    int chunk;

    FILE *fd;

    /* open file, get size, set chunk = to half the file, 
     * allocate memory, rewind back to begining of file
     */
    fd = fopen (fileName, "rb");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        ferror (fd);
        return 1;
    }
    fseek (fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    chunk = ftell (fd) / 2;

    if ((buffer = malloc (chunk * sizeof *buffer)) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    rewind (fd);

    /* read the first half of the file into buffer */
    fread (buffer, chunk, 1, fd); /* you should check return of each read */
    fclose (fd);

    /* create new file, write the contents of buffer into it */
    fd = fopen ("1_1.doc", "wb");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        ferror (fd);
        return 1;
    }
    fwrite (buffer, chunk, 1, fd); /* you should check return of each write */
    fclose (fd);

    /* reopen original file, go to half the file, read the 
     * remaining half of the file and store in buffer
     */
    fd = fopen (fileName, "rb");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        ferror (fd);
        return 1;
    }
    fseek (fd, chunk, SEEK_SET);
    fread (buffer, chunk, 1, fd); /* you should check return */
    fclose (fd);

    /* create a new file, write the second half of the file into it */
    fd = fopen ("1_2.doc", "wb");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        ferror (fd);
        return 1;
    }
    fwrite (buffer, chunk, 1, fd); /* check return */
    fclose (fd);

    free (buffer); /* free allocated memory */

    return 0;

}
```

**Input File**

```
$ cat 1.doc
Mon Feb 29 10:06:59 CST 2016
Mon Feb 29 10:06:59 CST 2016
Mon Feb 29 10:06:59 CST 2016
Mon Feb 29 10:06:59 CST 2016
```

**Example Use/Output Files**

```
$ ./bin/binread

$ l 1*
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 116 Apr  6 23:17 1.doc
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  58 Apr  6 23:18 1_1.doc
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  58 Apr  6 23:18 1_2.doc

$ cat 1_1.doc
Mon Feb 29 10:06:59 CST 2016
Mon Feb 29 10:06:59 CST 2016
```

Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

You've lost a half a byte, on average.

If the file size is even, then the file can be divided into two equal halves.

If the file size is odd, one chunk has to be one byte larger.

```
size_t length = ftell(fd);
size_t chunk1 = length / 2;
size_t chunk2 = length - chunk1;
```

And you really need to allocate space for the chunks; `buffer` cannot hold more than 2 bytes without scribbling on other memory, and those 2 bytes could be in read-only memory.